# Link-to child rout redirect to parent rout

Tags: ember.js

I have router like this

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('messages-faxes', function() {
    this.route('inbox');
  });
  this.route('contacts', function(){
    this.route('new');
  });
});
```

In header of page i have nave bar with link to messages-faxes/inbox

```
{{#link-to 'messages-faxes' tagName='li' }}
   {{link-to 'MESSAGES & FAXES' 'messages-faxes.inbox' }}
{{/link-to}}
```

To messages-faxes.index rout i add some code to redirect to messages-faxes.inbox

```
redirect: function(params) {
  this.transitionTo('messages-faxes.inbox');
}
```

If i click on link i have that backtrace in console

```
Preparing to transition from 'contacts.index' to 'messages-faxes.inbox' 
Transitioned into 'messages-faxes.inbox'
Preparing to transition from 'messages-faxes.inbox' to 'messages-faxes.index'
Transitioned into 'messages-faxes.inbox'
```

How to prevent transition from child rout(messages-faxes.inbox) to parent(messages-faxes.index)? Or it is good for ember?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The messages-faxes,index route is NOT a parent route from messges-faxes.inbox. It is a sibling.

But you have in your navbar two different routes to transition. Adjust it this way:

```
{{#link-to 'messages-faxes.inbox' tagName='li' }}
  {{link-to 'MESSAGES & FAXES' 'messages-faxes.inbox' }}
{{/link-to}}
```

Comment: It works correct. But i use {{#link-to 'messages-faxes.inbox' tagName='li' }} to mark as active MESSAGES & FAXES nav folder on page. I have a several sub-routes in messages-faxes route. And i show them as a tabs on page. I need to mark as active  MESSAGES & FAXES nav folder when i am on subroute like messages-faxes.sent or messages-faxes.trash. Can you tell me how to fix this?

Comment: This is a different question. Maybe you should mark this as solved and ask that other question in a new thread. Also, you should write what css framework you are using since it looks to me, that it depends on that...

Comment: Fix this. I add willTransition action in application route. willTransition(transition){
      console.log(transition.targetName)
      if (transition.targetName == 'messages-faxes.index'){
        transition.abort();
      }
    }